# To what extent is the DNS used outside of the World Wide Web?

Tags: dns, internet, web

I understand that it is vital for web client-server communication, however is the DNS used for other inter networked communications for example video streaming or online gaming? If so how is it used?

Comment: It's not just client-server, but also peer-to-peer.  When I installed a modem/router that did not provide local DNS, I could not use a Linux hostname in the `ping` command.  I had to use IP addresses to access each Linux host in my LAN.

Comment: The "internet" is simply a enormous intranet everyone is connected to.  DNS translates host names (domains) to up addresses.  Your question isn't clear

Comment: Outside of being used for the "**WWW / Internet**", it's limited to what you can use it for internally per domain perhaps where there are DNS server(s) that maintains the DNS settings for the TCP/IP clients connected to the network to resolve the internal DNS pointers to IP addresses for servers, services, URLS, and on and on.  For Sheezy too broad 100%!!! Again you're asking about NOT being related to Internet so it's for internal network usages then and all internal networks can be different. What extent, the sky's the limit, you tell me, I'll tell you, he can tell her, or I'll just guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is used to translate a domain name to an IP.

This is used just about any time that a client wants to talk to a server, regardless of whether that server is a Web server, or a game server, or any other type.  So it's extremely common.

Answer (score 2):

It's used any time a resource has to be accessed by name. Lots of resources move around, including Internet servers of all types. This includes those used by games, but also applications of all kinds.